# Amazon Cloudfront to serve images only

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

We use Amazon Cloudfront to host all our product images. We set up cloudfront so that `cdn.mydomain.com` will get the images from `www.mydomain.com`.

Recently, we have discovered that `cdn.mydomain.com` has been indexed with Google because when we type `cdn.mydomain.com`, Cloudfront serves full HTML version of our www version.

Is there anyway so that we allow Cloudfront to serve images only (jpg, gif, and png)?

Any suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: Where is CloudFront getting the content?  From your servers (what web server platform are you running?) or from S3?

Answer (score 3):

CloudFront provides a easy way to do this, in your distribution configuration go to the **cache behaviors** create a behavior that does only cache *.jpg

or if it is in images folder you can set rule to cache requests to that folder alone, its easy as that!

but definitely **don't use rewrite rules**! then there's no point in using cdn!!

Comment: Ugh - that's true.  I need to edit my answer to clarify.  It needs to rewrite the outbound html tags.

Comment: One problem I ran into is that you cannot remove the default 'behaviour', which matches '*' so even if you create a rule with higher precedence that matches e.g. only `/images/*` the default will still match for any other requests. I've 'solved' this by setting the default behaviour to require signed requests. Since none of the requests coming in are actually signed, they get a 403 Forbidden reply, due to a "MissingKey", effectively blocking the request.